# Show only DIV HOMEPAGE

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to put `.masthead-fixed .the main` remaining pages ... just not on HOME PAGE

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">

 <?php if (!is_home() || !is_front_page()) { ?> 

<?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
<div id="site-header">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
        <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
    </a>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">

    <div class="header-main">
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>

        <div class="search-toggle">
            <a href="#search-container" class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></a>
        </div>

        <nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Primary Menu', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></button>
            <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></a>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="search-container" class="search-box-wrapper hide">
        <div class="search-box">
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</header><!-- #masthead -->
<?php } ?>
```

This is the site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

This is code CSS:

```
.masthead-fixed .site-main {
 margin-top: 48px;
 display:none;
```

How do you solve this?

I build a Wordpress theme and I want to have content only and not on other pages ... HOME PAGE

Answer (score 0):

```
.masthead-fixed, .site-main {
```

You need to put a coma to affect a css rule to many html elements.